# Encapsulate PHP repeating section/array to a string

Tags: php, html, arrays, string

I have a repeating section from a MySQL look-up - the code (including HTML) is this:

```
<br>
    <?php do { ?>
    <?php if (substr($row_mDetails['Lo'], 0, 1) === '-') {echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));} else {echo '+'.str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));}; ?> | 
    <?php if (substr($row_mDetails['La'], 0, 1) === '-') {echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));} else {echo '+'.str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));}; ?>
| <?php echo $row_mDetails['Name']; ?> | 0 |<br>
      <?php } while ($row_mDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($mDetails)); ?>
```

How do I get the output of this to a string (for example, `$MyDataString = *the output from the above*`)

Whenever I try this, I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

(Edited to include surrounding HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `php` from the start of the second line. Then the code runs fine. I would advocate making this code slightly more readable:

```
<?php
do {
    if (substr($row_mDetails['Lo'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    } else {
        echo '+' . str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    }
?> | <?php
    if (substr($row_mDetails['La'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));
    } else {
        echo '+' . str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));
    }
?> | <?php
    echo $row_mDetails['Name'];
?> | 0 |<br> <?php
} while ($row_mDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($mDetails));
?>
```

I removed the unnecessary `;` from after your `else`s.

It's a question of personal preference but you could also replace your

```
?> | <?php
```

with

```
echo " | ";
```

to avoid opening and closing tags.

#### edit

If you want to build your string in a loop, you could do something like this:

```
do {
    if (substr($row_mDetails['Lo'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        $str .= str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    } else {
        $str .= '+' . str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    }
    $str .= " | ";

    if (substr($row_mDetails['La'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        $str .= str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));
    } else {
        $str .= '+' . str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5));
    }
    $str .= " | " . $row_mDetails['Name'] . " | 0 |<br> ";
} while ($row_mDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($mDetails));
```

Comment: Thanks for the good practice tips, Tom. What I'm trying to do is get it to a point where I can simply have (to use your code above) something like `$datstring = do {
    if (substr($row_mDetails['Lo'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    } else {
        echo '+' . str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['Lo'], 5));
    }
?> | <?php
    if (substr($row_mDetails['La'], 0, 1) === '-') {
        echo str_replace('.', '', number_format($row_mDetails['La'], 5))...` etc, etc. Make sense?

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with that. Firstly, you can't assign the result of a loop to a variable like that. Secondly, the parts outside of the `<?php ?>` are not evaluated by PHP so they can't be part of the string.

Comment: I thought That might be the case. What are my options for getting what I want?

Comment: thank you so much. That is a beautiful solution. Thanks for your generous time.

Answer (score 0):

could you paste it with your html or if there isn't any why are you ending the php and starting it again and again?

PS: on second row you have " php if " yet you haven't closed the earlier with ?> and you forgot "

Comment: Of course. There isn't a lot at the moment, but I have now included what there is.